# Smart references in C++

Tags: c++, reference, smart-pointers

Edit: Welp, I guess this was a terrible idea.

Is it possible to make a smart reference in C++ (for a specific class, since you can't overload the . operator) with the same semantics as a normal C++ reference, but which is reseated when used in an STL container?

For example, if I have some `int_ref` class with the normal integer operators overloaded, and construction and assignment looks like this:

```
class int_ref{
    int * p;
public:
    int_ref(int * ip) : p(ip) {}
    int_ref(const int_ref & other) : p(other.p) { 
        /* maybe some refcounting stuff here */ 
    }
    int_ref & operator = (const int_ref & other){
        if (!p) 
            throw something_bad();
        *p = *other.p;
        return *this;
    }
    void reseat(const int_ref & other){
        p = other.p;
    }
}
```

Then I can't use this with `std::vector` since it won't reseat the references, and I don't want this kind of thing:

```
std::vector<int_ref> vec;
int_ref five = new int(5);
vec.push_back(five);
vec.push_back(new int(1));
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end()); // the value of five is now 1
```

I can use rvalue references to make it play nice with the STL,

```
int_ref & operator=(int_ref && other){
    reseat(other);
    return *this;
}
```

But then a function that returns an `int_ref` would use the rvalue overload, and I'd get this:

```
int_ref make_number(){
    return new int(10);
}

int_ref ref = new int(5);
int_ref other = ref;
other = make_number();    // instead of copying, as a reference would,
                          // other now points to something other than ref
```

Is there a way around this? Is this just a terrible idea in general?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: ... what's wrong with an `int *` or `std::shared_ptr<int>`?

Comment: This is for sugar reasons, basically. I basically want a `shared_ptr` which has the same interface as the class it's pointing to.

Comment: @zounds: What do you mean by "the same interface"?

Comment: If it's just to avoid `->` instead of `.`, forget it. It may be possible, but it's a lot of work for absolutely no gain. No, aesthetics don't count.

Comment: Not interface in an inheritance sense. I kind of want to get something like the way Java object references work, where you just use . instead of ->, but where the assignment operator has deep copy semantics.

Comment: @delnan, it's not so much the `.` vs `->` that bugs me, it's that overloaded operators like `[]` all have to use `(*ptr)[]`.

Comment: You could take a look at [`std::ref`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982489.aspx), maybe that's useful.

Comment: @zounds: the correct, idiomatic way to do this is to use a (smart) pointer. C++ is not Java, and trying to make it behave like Java or look like Java is only going to end in pain for you, and twice as much pain for anyone else unfortunate enough to read your code. If you want a reseatable reference, the name for that in C++ is "pointer"

Comment: @jalf yeah, the responses to this have convinced me to not bother, though I just want to note, I don't quite want Java references either, since the `operator=` is what's in contention here, and Java's `=` works just like C++'s pointer `=`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One problem with even trying to do this is `operator&`. For a reference, it gives you the address of the referand (since references have no address). For a element of a container, though, it's expected to give you the address of the element (since those do have addresses).

So, an element of a container cannot mimic reference semantics in this respect. If you overload `operator&` to return the address of the referand, then for example the contiguous storage guarantee of `vector` is violated, since it says `&v[n] == &v[0] + n` for all `0 <= n < v.size()`

`boost::addressof()` was invented to work around this problem, so that you don't have to use `&` to get the address of an object in generic code. But even the standard is too lazy to say `static_cast<T*>(&static_cast<char&>(v[n]))` rather than `&v[n]`. Even when you're thinking of using it, it's quite difficult to decide when you want the actual address of the object, and when you want the address that the author of the object thinks you want. It's best just never to overload unary `operator&`. That means you'll get a partial version of reference semantics, which potentially is confusing in its own way.

Answer (score 4):

What you probably want to use is a boost:ptr_{container}.

You store pointers in the container (and the container takes ownership). But when accessing the object you get references to the object not the pointer.

```
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp>

int main()
{
     boost::ptr_vector<int>    data;
     data.push_back(new int(5));


     std::cout << data[0] << "\n";  // Prints 5 as you get a reference to the object.
}
```

Alternatively if you just want references. Then you can use boost:ref